# Nested loop outputs duplicate numbers

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this code where each candlestick enters a for loop where it tests whether it hits a certain support level with a tolerance of 5 %, the problem is that I have duplicate outputs. why ?!

```
for i in range(0, len(df['Close'])):

  for j in range (len(ssupport)) : 

    if (ssupport[j] * .98) <= df['Low'][i-1] <= (ssupport[j] * 1.02 ) :
        if df['Low'][i] >= df['High'][i-1] :

            stest.append (df['High'][i])

            if (j+1 < len(ssupport)) :
                nexts.append (ssupport[j+1])
            else:   
                nexts.append (ssupport[j])  
print (stest)
```

output :

```
[109.792, 109.792, 109.792, 109.792, 109.792, 109.792, 112.019997, 112.019997, 112.019997, 112.019997, 109.920998, 109.920998, 109.920998, 109.920998, 109.920998, 109.920998, 108.723, 108.723, 108.723, 108.723, 108.723, 108.723, 108.528, 108.528, 108.528, 108.528, 108.528, 108.528, 108.528, 107.193001, 107.193001, 107.193001, 107.496002, 107.496002, 107.496002, 107.496002, 107.496002, 107.847, 107.847, 107.847, 107.847, 107.847, 107.847, 109.190002, 109.190002, 109.190002, 109.190002, 109.190002, 109.190002]
```

Comment: Hi Miky, without the actual data it is hard for us to find the problem. Could you try to minimize the problem. Also add some examples of input and expected output.

Comment: @UliSotschok , the input is historical OHLC data for USDJPY pair, the output is exactly what I want as mentioned in the post. the problem is duplicate output
for example: 109.792 is the right output, however, it's printed 6 consecutive times, why?

Answer (score 0):

Because I have to guess the problem here is one possible explanation.

This is just how nested for loops work. See in this simple example all `i`'s are printed multiple consecutive times and the `j` also repeats after some time.

```py
for i in range(0, 5):
    for j in range(10, 15):
        print(str(i) + " " + str(j))
```

Output:

```
10 0
11 0
12 0
13 0
14 0
10 1
11 1
12 1
13 1
14 1
10 2
11 2
12 2
13 2
14 2
10 3
11 3
12 3
13 3
14 3
10 4
11 4
12 4
13 4
14 4
```

### Possible solutions:

1. Only add an item if it is not already in the list
2. Use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of a list (Achieves what 1. would do but without any extra code)
3. break the inner loop after you added an item
4. Adjust your if statements